# como debo de implementar el código o cual es la propiedad del "command Button" para que solo se ejecute dando clic sobre él?

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual utilizo Primer faces el "command Button" el cual está en el inicio del formulario, y cuando estoy diligenciando los otros campos del formulario se ejecuta sin dar clic o estar encima del botón, alguien que sepa o me pueda ayudar como hacer para que la acción del botón solamente se ejecute cuando haga clic sobre este botón o alguna propiedad que me ayude con este caso?.. Muchas gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

El código del `commandButton` es el siguiente:

```
  <div class="centerButton">
        <p:commandButton 
                action="Ejecuccion" 
                icon="ui-icon-person" 
                value=" Ejecutar sentencia"  process="@this" >
        </p:commandButton>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar a utilizar un `p:commandLink` con el icono y así evitar el problema de la tecla enter.

El uso del commandLink es similar al del commandbutton con la diferencia de que este "pinta" un enlace `<a>` (por lo que no hace submit). Para usar el icono que utilizas en la pregunta, yo utilizaría un `h:outputText`. Te dejo el código aquí abajo.

```
<div class="centerButton">
    <p:commandLink action="Ejecuccion" process="@this">
      <h:outputText value="Ejecutar sentencia" class="ui-icon ui-icon-person"/>   
    </p:commandLink>
</div>
```

Un saludo

**Edición**

Gracias a @Alvaro Montoro por señalar que debería mejorar la respuesta

Comment: Hola Mikel, aunque esta respuesta podría ser útil para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal si pudieras editarla para añadir algo más de información. Por ejemplo, ¿cómo se aplicaría ese `p:commandLink` al código de la pregunta para resolver el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es poner una propiedad que se llama **immediate** que tienen estos botones para poder procesar solo la acción del botón tambien si quieres actualizar solo una parte del formulario usas **update="nombre del componente a actualizar"**

```
<div class="centerButton">
        <p:commandButton 
            action="Ejecuccion" 
            icon="ui-icon-person" 
            value=" Ejecutar sentencia"  process="@this" 
           immediate="true">
        </p:commandButton>    
    </div>
```

Comment: hola @Raul Cacacho, ya implemente lo que me dijiste, pero se sigue ejecutando el "action" del "command button" el cual me abre un formulario el cual no quiero abrir todavía, solamente necesito que se ejecute el "action" o ejecute este código cuando doy clic nada más sobre el botón(CommandButton),igualmente muchas gracias.

Comment: @Alexander podrias actualizar la pregunta con todo tu codigo xhtml

Answer (score 0):

El componente p:commandButton no tiene eventos o disparadores periódicos, por lo que hay algo en tu código que afecta su funcionamiento.

Verifica que no hay ningún componente en tu código que active o haga un update sobre tu commandButton.

```
<p:commandButton 
   action="Ejecuccion" 
   icon="ui-icon-person" 
   value=" Ejecutar sentencia"  process="@this" 
   immediate="true">
 </p:commandButton>
```

Notas:

1. action -> Implica una navegabilidad en el código, supongo que es lo
   que quieres hacer, de otra manera deberías de tener un
   actionLisener.
2. value -> Puede ser tu problema, ya que es aquí donde va el label del
       botón, y tienes en texto una ejecución de sentencias.
3. immediate -> Para que realice la acción sin validar ni tener en
       cuenta otras partes del formulario, pasa de cualquier error. **No
       recomendable.**
4. process -> Por defecto no es necesario añadirlo, pero si quieres estar seguro de que se realiza la petición del componente no está demás añadirlo.

Un saludo.

**EDICIÓN**

actionLisener o action -> Son los eventos que invocan al controlador/bean para realizar el evento predefinido. Verifica que no lo haces en el value.

**EDICIÓN**

> Para eliminar el comportamiento por defecto del evento al presionar la
>   tecla ENTER utiliza un botón "tonto".

Primefaces solution:

```
<p:defaultCommand target="dummy"/>
<p:commandButton id="dummy" process="@none" global="false" style="display:none;"/>
```

p:defaultCommand -> Cambia el comportamiento que describes por defecto y redirige la acción ENTER al componente que tu selecciones.

Comment: un saludo @UHDante, gracias por tu aporte, lo que sucede o hasta donde tengo entendido es que al utilizar el "prime faces" un "commandButton", por ejemplo estoy llenando un cuadro de texto y doy enter, este ejecuta  primero el botón que se encuentre en el formulario o este caso el primer "command Button" del formulario.                            
 Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @Alexander ¿Lo que quieres es evitar el comportamiento por defecto al pulsar enter?? ¿Que no se te ejecute el commandButton en al realizar dicha acción?

Comment: exacto @UHDante, ya que al presionar enter se ejecuta el commandButton sin yo querer ejecutar lo.

Comment: @Alexander en la edición de mi respuesta te he añadido una solución si estás utilizando primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

Como al utilizar el "commandButton" de "Prime faces" este ejecuta se ejecuta(el primer commandButton que se encuentre en el formulario)siempre que presione enter entonces la solución que encontré provisionalmente fue crear un command button que no haga nada y no afecte el buen funcionamiento del código o proceso:

```
     <div class="centerButton">
            <p:remoteCommand name="find" action="Usuario"
                immediate="true">
            </p:remoteCommand>
            <h:commandButton image="/images/blanco.png"
                styleClass="iconAcciones" immediate="true">
                <p:ajax event="click" oncomplete="findUsuario()" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
      <div class="centerButton">
        <p:commandButton 
            action="Ejecuccion" 
            icon="ui-icon-person" 
            value=" Ejecutar sentencia"  process="@this" >
        </p:commandButton>    
      </div>
        <div class="centerButton"></div>
        <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema en sí entiendo que no es que alguien pueda seleccionar con tab tu botón y presionar enter o la barra espaciadora, sino el comportamiento del formulario de que al dar enter se envíe completo el formulario.

Si lo metiste en un formulario normal del `core` de [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) puedes eliminar este comportamiento **en un formulario determinado** mediante

```
<h:form onsubmit="return false;">
```

en el que como verás redefines el comportamiento del evento enviar del formulario para que no haga absolutamente nada.

ahora si no es así, como primefaces usa [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) por defecto puedes poner el siguiente código en un script:

```
$('form').off('keypress.disableAutoSubmitOnEnter').on('keypress.disableAutoSubmitOnEnter', function(event) {
    if (event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER && $(event.target).is(':input:not(textarea,:button,:submit,:reset)')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

que como verás lo que hace es reemplazar el comportamiento por defecto de enviar **para todos los formularios** que existan en la página.

Fuente original (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117166/6999690